# performance on loads of appended css animated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I've loads of divs appended randomly to the body:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1020; i++) {
    var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)),
    randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    allCubes += '<div id="cube'+i+'" class="cube" style="position: absolute; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 7px; height: 7px; z-index: -1;"></div>';
}  
    $('body').append(allCubes);

    for (var i = 0; i < 1020; i++) {
       cubes['cube' + i] = $('#cube' + i)
    }
```

them I have a function which animates every single div related to one `#fixed` div.

```
var row = 9,        
        t = 0;
        $fixed.css({'background-color': '#000', left: '25%', top: '35%'});
    var fixedOffs = $fixed.offset();


    cubes[0].transition({ top: fixedOffs.top+row, left: fixedOffs.left, 'background-color': '#000',delay: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    cubes[1].transition({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*2, left: fixedOffs.left, 'background-color': '#000',delay: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    cubes[2].transition({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*3, left: fixedOffs.left, 'background-color': '#000',delay: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    cubes[3].transition({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*4, left: fixedOffs.left+row, 'background-color': '#000',delay: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
      // until cubes[1019]...
```

yeah I've been writing all the numbers and coordinates down for each div. I'm using css3 transition (transit.js, which has syntax like `.animate()` ) to make it as performant as possible. But unfortunenately it is really laggy.
Does anyone an idea how to handle this loads of divs in that way I want to.

Note: every single div has its own position, there is a system but its different everytime.

Comment: Can you provide a working demo of your current code in http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: not performance related....but sure simpler ways to loop array of elements to create your transition code in about 3 lines and also ignore all ID's using indexing

Comment: You might want to look into using the Greensock Animation Platform http://www.greensock.com/ for high performance animation of many elements.  Have a look at the comparison to jquery performance: http://www.greensock.com/jquery/

Comment: CSS transitions can get a bit laggy when there is a lot going on. Greensock is pretty good. Here's a speed test/comparison: http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html If you test it against Zepto you'll get a pretty good idea of CSS transitions VS GSAP.

Comment: Using `translate` instead of `left/top` in your CSS will increase the performance a little bit. [Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: thanks guys, I will do it with gsap and hopefully its a lot better!